# Bash if number greater then failing

Tags: bash, sh

Can anyone explain to me why this is failing?  0111 is greater then 99 but i'm not getting an Invalid database message.

```
db=0111
echo $db
£ Verify db is within the correct range
if [[ $db -lt 0 ]] || [[ $db -gt 99 ]]; then
    echo "Invalid database"
fi
```

If i change db to db=111 or even db=01111 the function works as expected.

Comment: _Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers._ – https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-arithmetic-evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because as @Koiro told in the comment:

> > Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.

you should enforce the 10based arithmetics

```
db=0111
echo $db
# Verify db is within the correct range
if [[ 10#$db -lt 0 ]] || [[ 10#$db -gt 99 ]]; then
    echo "Invalid database"
fi
```

prints

```
0111
Invalid database
```

Comment: Might look a little tidier with arithmetic expressions: `(( 10#$db < 0 || 10#$db > 99 ))`

Comment: @glennjackman yes, you're right. I just copy&pasted the OP's script.

Comment: That is kind of what I was thinking, thanks for the example on how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`0111 == 73`, therefore it's smaller than 99.

```
$ echo $((0111))
73
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by actually explaining octal conversion and why this behavior is the way it is.